# Store dimensions of panels after resizing using <p:resizable>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, resize

I am trying to retain the dimensions of a `<p:panel>` after resizing, so that when the user logs in, he can have his widgets with the same width and height. How can changes to the panels can be persisted after they are resized using `<p:resizable>`?  Once I retrieve them from db, how do I make changes to the CSS properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle resizing with AJAX when using `p:resizable`:

```
<p:resizable for="myPanel">
  <p:ajax listener="#{myBean.handleResize}"/>
</p:resizable>
```

and in backing bean you define function:

```
public void handleResize(ResizeEvent e) {
  width = e.getWidth();
  height = e.getHeight();
  // Now persist height and width...
}

private int width;
private int height;

// getters and setters for width and height

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  // init width and height from db...
}
```

Later you can use this `width` and `height` to set initial size of `p:panel`:

```
<p:panel style="width:#{myBean.width}px;height:#{myBean.height}px;">
```

Comment: thank you for that! I am actually trying to retain the panel size so that when the user logs in, he can have his widgets with the same width and height. Once I retrieve them from db, how do I make changes to the css properties?

Comment: I don't know on which component you are setting height and width. Please post some code.

Comment: Don't add in comment, edit your question. I edited my answer to be appropriate for this.